# Bootstrap 3 - using full width of .container-fluid with multiple .form-group and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site using Bootstrap 3.3.6. It features a "sign up for newsletter" box which currently looks like this:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I'd like the text "sign up for newsletter" to appear on the same row as the form fields - so everything is horizontally aligned - on large/medium devices.

However, when it goes down to a small device I want everything stacked, which I've got working and looks like this:

[image]

So the markup I've used is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <form>
            <h4>Sign up for Newsletter</h4>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="company" maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Company" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="250" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
                </div>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

Even if I put the text "Sign up for Newsletter" inside a `.form-group` it still appears on the top line above the form fields.

How can I get everything on just 1 line? Clearly there is enough space to make this work on the first screenshot, which is a medium device.

I considered using the `.col-` classes but this doesn't seem to work as I'd need 6 of them which would only be `.col-md-2` making the form fields so small that the `placeholder` attribute text would be unreadable.

Please can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to use a single `form-group` in combination with `form-inline`.  With that you could greatly condense your code into something similar to below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group form-inline text-center">
  <h4 class="form-control-static">Sign up for Newsletter</h4><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
  <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" />
  <input type="text" name="company" maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Company" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" />
  <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="250" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
</div>
```

Applying `form-control-static` to your header text will cause it to display in a fashion similar to elements with `form-control`.  The `<br>` has classes to render it visible only in `xs` and `sm` breakpoints and allows for the spacing between inputs.

It works... but if I'm being honest it's kind of ugly.  The Grid is probably a superior option in terms of how much easier it is to offer responsive, flexible breakpoints... but you'd probably have to compromise (as you indicated) on input sizes or otherwise stack them differently by breakpoint.

If you wanted to structure this using Grid though you would probably do something like the below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">
      <h4 class="form-control-static">Sign up for Newsletter</h4><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">
      <input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">
      <input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">
      <input type="text" name="company" maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Company" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 text-center">
      <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="250" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required><br class="visible-xs visible-sm" clear="all" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code the grid alters at various breakpoints and shows the form elements either in a single row (Medium and Greater) or at 2-per row (Small) or 1 per row (XS).